# Média e contagem para cada produto SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando fazer uma atualização de uma tabela no meu banco de dados em duas colunas novas, uma que trás a média das avaliações e outra que trás o número de avaliações.

Esses dados são obtidos através de duas tabelas, a relação entre elas é o `id` e o `product_id`.

Tentei o seguinte código:

```sql
UPDATE product 
INNER JOIN 
 product_review ON product.id = product_review.product_id
SET 
 product.review_rating = (
  SELECT AVG(product_review.rating) WHERE state='approved'
 );
```

Mas ele retorna a média de todos os produtos e não de cada um em separado, alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente fazer um teste fazendo um Join com uma tabela derivada onde é calculada a média. Ex:

```
UPDATE product 
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT product_id, AVG(product_review.rating) as review_rating
  FROM product_review
  WHERE state='approved'
  GROUP BY product_id
) rv
  on product.id = rv.product_id 
SET product.review_rating = rv.review_rating
```

Nessa tabela derivada você também pode fazer a contagem de avaliações que você citou.